# Apex: Dynamically get fields for an SObject - no hardcoding

Tags: apex, describesobject

It states in Salesforce Apex docs that I can get fields for a particular SObject (standard or custom) in the following way:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Custom__c.fields.getMap();
```

But this requires hardcoding. as I need to hardcode the API name of the SObject : Schema.SObjectType.

Is there a way to access all fields on an SObject dynamically without hard coding? I am getting a list of all SObjects in my org by calling `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, but this leaves me with API names of individual SObjects. There is no way to get all those SObject's field info dynamically. Am I missing something or it is just not possible?

I want something like:

```
List <Schema.SObjectField> fieldList = Schema.SObjectType.get(SObject_API_Name).fields;
```

Answer (score 57):

You don't need to hard code the Object name as you have specified, you can indeed do it dynamically, for example:

```
SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = accountType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. But somehow I weren't able to find the getGlobalDescribe().get(strname) flavour of this in SF docs ... although the hardcoded example is pretty common. Thanks again.

Comment: `getGlobalDescribe` returns a `Map<String,Schema.SObjectType>`, so you're using the Map class's get method.

Comment: @S_2013 the getGlobalDescribe() method is under the Schema class , which is under the System namespace. you can find it here  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_schema.htm#apex_methods_system_schema. There is another Schema namespaces which as another set of functions.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_Schema.htm

Answer (score 27):

The docs suggest you use the newer [Schema.describeSObjects(List) method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describeSObject.htm) - that lets you pass one or more names of objects as a list, and get back the results. Here's the sample code:

```
// sObject types to describe
String[] types = new String[]{'Account','Merchandise__c'};
// Make the describe call
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);
System.debug('Got describe information for ' + results.size() + ' sObjects.');
// For each returned result, get some info
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
    System.debug('sObject Label: ' + res.getLabel());
    System.debug('Number of fields: ' + res.fields.getMap().size());
    System.debug(res.isCustom() ? 'This is a custom object.' : 'This is a standard object.');
    // Get child relationships
    Schema.ChildRelationship[] rels = res.getChildRelationships();
    if (rels.size() > 0) {
        System.debug(res.getName() + ' has ' + rels.size() + ' child relationships.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Faster than describe global when you know the names you're looking for, important for the new governor limits.

Comment: How about for custom metadata? `Super_Metadata__mdt`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Schema.SObjectType` to get the object type dynamically:

```
String obj = 'Account';

Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(obj); 
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe(); 
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = describeResult.fields.getMap();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String sobjectname = 'Case' ; //object api name
String fieldapiName = 'Status'; //Field api name
String fieldTypeName = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sobjectname).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(fieldApiName).getDescribe().getType().name().toupperCase(); 
System.debug('*** fieldTypeName = ' + fieldTypeName);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to access all fields on an SObject dynamically without hard coding:

```
Schema.SObjectField result = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('yourObjectName as a string').getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('yourFieldName as a string');
```

Did it not work in 2013 ?

#archeology

Answer (score -4):

The Summer '16 release has a nice function to retrieve populated fields from an object: [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm)

I had a simple use case of generating a CSV file from an arbitrary list of sObjects for which it provided an easy solution.

Using getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() you can retrieve a map of field names and their corresponding values without knowing the object type.

```
sObject data = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Lead LIMIT 1];
Map<String, Object> fieldsAndValues = data.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It doesn't give you all fields on the object, only a subset of them. And you need actual records.

Comment: @AdrianLarson , may I know what you mean by subset . Because I check release note https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm , it does not state limitation. However I stil face some of the field is not return although class version is 46.