# Retrieve a list of an object fields

Tags: apex

I have an object with a lot of fields, is there a method in apex which returns a list of the object's fields?

Comment: You get use the Schema describe to do this.  I don't remember it off the top of my head but if you do a google search it should be easy to find.

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Apex Describe to do this:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult oppDescribe = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = oppDescribe.fields.getMap();
for (Schema.SObjectFIeld field: fields.values())
{
  //All field info you need is in here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that by using  [Schema.describeSObjects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describeSObject.htm)(List) method.

```
// sObject types to describe

String[] types = new String[]{'Account','Merchandise__c'};

 // Make the describe call
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);

  System.debug('Got describe information for ' + results.size() + ' sObjects.');

// For each returned result, get some info
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
System.debug('sObject Label: ' + res.getLabel());
System.debug('Number of fields: ' + res.fields.getMap().size());
System.debug(res.isCustom() ? 'This is a custom object.' : 'This is a standard object.');
// Get child relationships
Schema.ChildRelationship[] rels = res.getChildRelationships();
if (rels.size() > 0) {
    System.debug(res.getName() + ' has ' + rels.size() + ' child relationships.');
}
 }
```

Refer this question as well [Apex: Dynamically get fields for an SObject - no hardcoding](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21213/apex-dynamically-get-fields-for-an-sobject-no-hardcoding)